# Radius Of Convergence-Polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series

giving the following power series$$1+2x+x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5$$
Find the radius of convergence. for which value does it converge when $x=\frac{1}{2}$

How should I approach this? it is a finite series so for all finite $x$ there is a finite value.

As for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ all that is needed is to plug it into the equation?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, this finite series does converge for all $x$, hence its radius of convergence is $R = \infty$. The value at $x = \frac 12$ is obtained by pluging $\frac 12$ into the equation, giving 
$$ 1 + 1 + \frac 14 + \frac 14 + \frac 1{16} + \frac 1{16} = 2 + \frac 12 + \frac 18 = \frac{21}{8} $$